# How to save user-entered line breaks from a TextArea to a email content

Tags: javascript, java, angular, email

I am sending email with user enterd space and line break its work ok till backend but when i see this content in my mail its in one line.

Example:

```
this is
  test text
```

this text display in email like this:

```
this is test text
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] that shows what format you are sending the e-mail in. Also is it Java or JavaScript, which are two very different things, or is there a reason you are asking about both front-end and back-end tech?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for the same

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```